# SQL: Need help to group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

this is my table:

| Start | Stop | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-15 | Rom |
| 2022-02-16 | 2022-03-31 | Rom |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-05-10 | London |
| 2022-05-11 | 2022-06-11 | London |
| 2022-06-12 | 2022-07-10 | Paris |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-08-10 | Rom |

I like to get this result:

| Start | Stop | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-31 | Rom |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-11 | London |
| 2022-06-12 | 2022-07-10 | Paris |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-08-10 | Rom |

If i use:

```
SELECT City, MIN(Start) as STA, MAX(Stop) AS STO FROM living GROUP BY City
```

i get:

| Start | Stop | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-08-10 | Rom |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-11 | London |
| 2022-06-12 | 2022-07-10 | Paris |

Comment: I don't see how you are able to associate row 2 with row 1 to get row 1 in your desired outcome. Is it the case that there is only 1 'bus'?

Comment: This is known as a gaps-and-islands problem. Basically you need to run some logic to label "consecutive rows of the same city" as a unique "group" (island), then group by that label. But, that logic depends on whether you're using MySQL 8 or MySQL 5.x (so, which are you using?)

Comment: I am using MySQL 8. I can check if i have more columns like an ID but at this time i only have these fields. They should be grouped by time without any gaps in the same city ...

Comment: You **imply** via your sample data and expected result that the order of rows is important - but in SQL you CANNOT assume that the rows will be handled in any specific order unless you literally specify what the order is to be

Comment: But i can order it ORDER BY start, stop .... so i can imply it is orderd? or not?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell The data is sortable by the timestamp columns. The only assumed information is that there are no gaps or overlaps in the timeseries.

Comment: my point was that you MUST sort by something - not leave it to the "unsorted" row layout of the table, perhaps my expression of that wasn't clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH
  islands AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                  ORDER BY start) AS seq,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY start) AS city_seq
  FROM
    living
)
SELECT
  city,
  MIN(start),
  MAX(stop)
FROM
  islands
GROUP BY
  city,
  seq - city_seq
ORDER BY
  MIN(start)
```

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start)` just creates a sequence of integers starting from 1, having ordered the data by `start`.

Adding `PARTITION BY city` does the same thing, but creates a separate sequence for each city.

The trick is then to use `seq - city_seq`. That tells you how many rows there have been so far that are NOT the current city.

| Start | Stop | City | seq | city_seq | s - cs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-15 | Rom | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-02-16 | 2022-03-31 | Rom | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-05-10 | London | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-05-11 | 2022-06-11 | London | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-06-12 | 2022-07-10 | Paris | 5 | 1 | 4 |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-08-10 | Rom | 6 | 3 | 3 |

Then, the combination of `city` and `rows so far for other cities (seq - city_seq)` is a unique identifier for each "island" and can be used in a normal `GROUP BY`

***Edit:***

The above assumes there are no gaps or overlaps in the data, and so ordering by `start` is sufficient.

If there are gaps or overlaps a slightly longer approach is more customisable...

- whenever the previous row isn't 'the same city, but 1 day later', record a `1` for the row to indicate a "new island".
- cumulativel sum those values over time, creating unique identifiers for each "island"
- `GROUP BY` as normal

```
WITH
  islands AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE
      WHEN city  = LAG(city) OVER (ORDER BY start)
       AND start = LAG(stop) OVER (ORDER BY start) + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
      THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END
      AS island_marker
  FROM
    living
),
  island_ids AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(island_marker) OVER (ORDER BY start) AS island_id
  FROM
    islands
)
SELECT
  MIN(city),
  MIN(start),
  MAX(stop)
FROM
  island_ids
GROUP BY
  island_id
ORDER BY
  island_id
```

| Start | Stop | City | island_marker | island_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-15 | Rom | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-02-16 | 2022-03-31 | Rom | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-05-10 | London | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-05-11 | 2022-06-11 | London | 0 | 2 |
| 2022-06-12 | 2022-07-10 | Paris | 1 | 3 |
| 2022-07-11 | 2022-08-10 | Rom | 1 | 4 |

Comment: Thanks, can you explain: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                  ORDER BY start) and ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY start) AS city_seq plz

Comment: Yes, but I'm in my phone, so it'll be slow going.

Comment: row_number() over() is explained in documentation see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html